# NotImplementedException thrown when using ASP.net chart control

Tags: asp.net, charts

Has anyone got this exception thrown when using the the controls databinding methods??

I have a data structure like this

```
public class ChartData
{
   public int Year {get;set;}
   public decimal Stat {get;set;}
}
```

Its collection is

```
List<ChartData> cData;
```

So i  bind this object as

```
chart1.BindXY(cData,"Year",cData,"Stat");
```

I get same exception when using other databinding methods too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is chart1?
Is that an external charting component?

Open the charting component dll using reflector OR see the docs for appropriate method to use.

Comment: chart1 is the .net charting control. I am using it exactly the way the doc says

Answer (score -1):

NotImplementedException is added by Visual Studio when it creates a method stub in response to the "Generate Method Stub" context menu command on a call to non-existent class method.

Perhaps the charting control you're using simply hasn't been fully implemented, and the method you're trying to invoke is just a stub?

Comment: Chart Control is not a custom or 3rd party control. Its a new control from M$